# Passing data between JSF beans

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having this problem with passing on data between JSF beans.. What I want to do is when I login, pass the username to a next bean where I can use it. I have found many things about this but I can't get it to work in my project. What I've got is a UserService where I can manage my users. There's a method in here called getUsers(username). Now I'm trying to pass the username so I can retrieve my user-object.

xHtml:

```
        <h:link outcome="changeProfile" value="Change profile">
            <f:param name="username" value="#{userBean.username}" />
        </h:link>
```

changeProfileBean:

```
@Component("changeProfile")
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ChangeProfileBean implements Serializable {

private UserService userService;
private User user;

@ManagedProperty("#{param.username}")
private String username;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.username = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("username");

    try {
        if(username != null){
            user = userService.getUser(username);
        }
    } catch (UserServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Autowired
public ChangeProfileBean(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

What happens is that the changeUserbean will be created when the app is starting. And immediately after that runs the @PostConstruct where username obviously equals null. But when I call the changeUserBean it doesn't execute the @PostConstruct anymore..
Does anybody know what I could do?

UserBean:

```
@Component("userBean")
@Scope("session")
public class UserBean implements Serializable
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RepairService repairService;

    private String username;
    private String password;
```

Comment: Try making your bean request scoped.

Comment: Still the same result..

Comment: Can you post the code for the both beans? 
I do not know much about spring but are you sure @Autowired is used like that?

Comment: I'm not sure either. I'm starting to learn how to work with JSF.. This is for a project in school.. If you know how to use it, please tell me because I don't know :)

Comment: Can you post the code for the changeProfileBean please?

Comment: It is the changeUserBean. It's a little bit confusing I know but I refactored it and will update it here as well

Comment: Stop doing your beans both spring and jsf managed. If going to mix both technologies, I encourage you to use JSF for the view layer and Spring for services. Using both of them will end up in duplicate instances, where you control nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the difference between jsf and spring managed. As I was saying I'm still trying to learn this stuff. When is the bean JSF managed and when is it Spring managed?

Comment: Why do u need a postconstruct method ? It is always going ot be null, isnt it ?

Comment: I've found this [link](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html).
"You can only inject a managed property of the same or a broader scope. So for example injecting request parameters as a managed property in a view scoped bean is (unfortunately) not going to work." And indeed, it's always going to be null. So I was wondering how I could fix this. I also tried to make it sessionscoped but still not working..

Comment: Anyone? Please? I've been stuck with this problem for quiet some time...

Answer (score 2):

While you have already the data you need in a broader scope, just inject that backing-bean into `changeProfileBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ChangeProfileBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;

    public UserBean getUserBean(){
        return userBean;
    }
    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean){
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, this seems like a better way to pass data. But this doesn't change the fact that the bean is created at startup. The userbean is still null..

Comment: Maybe you should add a constuctor in the `ChangeProfileBean` managed-bean.